# FullCalendar retrieving data through HTTP

Tags: angular, angular6

I want to implement FullCalendar with the ability retrieving data through HTTP. And the ability to open a dialog box from the selected date. Is there a suitable library for such an implementation? Or a ready-made example?

Answer (score 0):

Provide full details about data through HTTP but you can call an API to get data and then display it in the [fullcalendar.io](https://fullcalendar.io/)

You can fulfill all this using fullcalendar.io.

This post covers the discussion about [how to open Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072645/fullcalendar-open-bootstrap-modal-on-dayclick) . I have add it in the following example.

Following example gives you an idea to show popup when you click on an event as well as Day Box.

Fiddle to view it runtime https://jsfiddle.net/alifaraze/mr53d7nz/27/

```html
<div id="calendar"></div>
<div id="calendarModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span> <span class="sr-only">close</span></button>
            <h4 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title"></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body"> </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>



$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [{
        id: 1,
        title: 'Full Day Event - Click Me',
        start: '2019-01-02',
        end: '2019-01-03',
        description: 'Full day event description'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Whole Week Event - Click Me',
        start: '2019-01-06',
        end: '2019-01-10',
        description: 'Whole week event description'
      }
      // more events here
    ],
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
      $(element).popover({
        title: function() {
          return "<B>" + event.title + "</B>";
        },
        placement: 'auto',
        html: true,
        trigger: 'click',
        animation: 'false',
        content: function() {
          return "<h3>"+ event.description +"</h3>"
        },
        container: 'body'
      }).popover('show');

    },
    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
      $('#modalTitle').html(date.format());
      $('#modalBody').html('Clicked on: ' + date.format() 
        +'<br/>Current view: ' + view.name 
        +'<br/>Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
      $('#calendarModal').modal();
    }
  });
})
```